# Проблема с 3WC Validator и WP

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap, html-validation

На сайте с WordPress установлена тема использующая Bootstrap (Версию не знаю). Имеется меню сайта.
Когда я смотрю страницы в Chrome вижу это:

```
<a class="navbar__dropdown-link" href="https://ссылка.ру/">ссылка</a>
```

А 3WC Validator получает вот это:

```
<a class="navbar__dropdown-link" href="https://ссылка.ру/" class="navbar__bottom-link link link_dark">ссылка</a>
```

Внимание вопрос.
Откуда?

Comment: UPD: Так видит MS Edge. Но что делать? Как убрать дублирующий класс?

Comment: Ну кто же знает откуда он у Вас там берется?

Comment: Нашёл откуда. Посмотрите ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался.

Это лечится тут, но вопрос надо задавать теперь в рамках другой темы.

```
class bootstrap_4_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_menu {

function start_lvl( &$output, $depth ){ // ul
    $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth); // indents the outputted HTML
    $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu navbar-dropdown__items$submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
}
```

function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ // li a span

```
$indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t",$depth) : '';

$li_attributes = '';
    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    
    $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown navbar-dropdown' : '';
    $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_anchestor) ? 'active' : '';
    $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    $classes[] = 'nav-item-' . $item->ID;
    if( $depth && $args->walker->has_children ){
        $classes[] = 'dropdown-menu';
    }
    
    $class_names =  join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';
    
    $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
    $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
    
    $output .= $indent . '<li ' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';
    
    $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
    
    $attributes .= ( $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' class="navbar-dropdown__toggle navbar__bottom-link link link_dark" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"' : ' class="navbar__bottom-link link link_dark"';
    
    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= ( $depth > 0 ) ? '<a class="navbar__dropdown-link"' . $attributes . '>' : '<a' . $attributes . '>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;
    
    $output .= apply_filters ( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

}
```